# Failed to scrape price related information from a site using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape `product title`, `description` and `price` of a product from a [webpage](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/terra-delyssa-tunisian-extra-virgin-olive-oil/6000196167258) using requests module. Although the content of that page is dynamic, most of the product information are available within page source in some script tag.

I have already grabbed `product title` and `description` from that page, which are within container variable. Unfortunately, I can't find the price within the container. So, I wish to scrape `Regular price: $8.97` and `Sale price: $5.97` from that site using requests module.

```
import re
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/terra-delyssa-tunisian-extra-virgin-olive-oil/6000196167258"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
items = re.findall(r"window.__PRELOADED_STATE__=(.*?);<",res.text)[0]
container = json.loads(items)['entities']['skus']
for i in container:
    product_name = container[i]['name']
    description = container[i]['longDescription']
    print(product_name,description)
```

> > How can I scrape price information from that site using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 242 reputation so i can't

anyhow https://www.walmart.ca/api/product-page/v2/price-offer send post request to this link you will obtain your things

or

simply use selenium

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wonder how did I miss that!! Thanks a lot for the pointer.